# EmberJS Error message: Assertion Failed: Cannot find model name

Tags: ember.js

I am in the mids of following: [Vic Ramon EmberJS tutorial](http://ember.vicramon.com/listing-leads). I reached the point where I am trying to list the leads and have the following setup:

**Adapter**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend()
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend()

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'
```

**Controller**

```
App.LeadsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sortProperties: ['firstName', 'lastName']
```

**Model**

```
App.Lead = DS.Model.extend
  firstName:  DS.attr('string')
  lastName:   DS.attr('string')
  email:      DS.attr('string')
  phone:      DS.attr('string')
  status:     DS.attr('string', defaultValue: 'new')
  notes:      DS.attr('string')


  fullName: (->
    @get('firstName') + ' ' + @get('lastName')
  ).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

**Routes**

```
App.LeadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: ->
    @store.findAll 'lead'
```

**Router**

```
App.Router.reopen
  location: 'auto'
  rootURL: '/'

App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'leads', path: '/'
  @resource 'lead', path: 'leads/:id'
```

**Template**

```
<article>
    <h1>Leads</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each lead in controller}}
        <li>{{#link-to 'lead' lead}}{{/link-to}}</li>
          {{lead.fullName}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</article>
```

The issue simply is when I redirect my browser to `http://localhost:3000` it shows me the list of fullNames but doesn't show me the anchor links. [image: Screenshot] Also another thing I seem to get in my chrome browser console is:

> Error message: Assertion Failed: Cannot find model name

#### Bonus Question

From reading a few books an tutorials I understand that you can include mixins as a way of injecting additional properties into Controllers or Views. So for example you can do:

```
Ember.View.extend(App.Editable)
```

But can you include a mixin into a **model**? As in can you do:

```
App.Lead = DS.Model.extend(App.SomeMixin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working jsbin for Ember 1.12 jsbin.com/mezakepemu/1/edit?html,js,console 
1) Links. You could try

```
<li>
  {{#link-to 'lead' lead}}
    {{lead.fullName}}
  {{/link-to}}
</li>
```

or

```
<li>{{link-to lead.fullName 'lead' lead}}</li>
```

And in modern Ember versions it's better to write

```
{{#each lead in model}} ... {{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each model as |lead|}} ... {{/each}}
```

2) Error message: Assertion Failed: Cannot find model name - please show the code where this error is thrown. Your leads route, controller and template looks normal.

3) Yes, mixins can be included in models and in every Ember.Object.

Comment: So having tried your initial suggestion `{{link-to 'lead' lead}} {{lead.fullName}}...` This didn't seem to output anything. I did try doing: `{{lead.length}}` which returned nothing however doing: `{{controller.length}}` returned 20 (number of records i have). Not entirely sure why the length wouldn't output when doing `{{lead.length}}`

Comment: What's your Ember version?

Comment: `Ember : 1.8.1
Ember Data : 1.13.4
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.11.2` If it is an issue to do with the version of ember I am using I may start again. Or is there a simple way to upgrade the ember version without having to start fresh

Comment: here is working jsbin for Ember 1.12 http://jsbin.com/mezakepemu/1/edit?html,js,console I can't help you with 1.8.1 it's too old for me.

Comment: Appreciate the example, I will try and start my project again with the latest version of ember.